# What is the best way to approach my boss with my two week resignation?

Tags: resignation, notice-period

I am not one that likes to "job hop".   I have been on my current job for one year. I was offered a better job in the same field, which pays quite a bit more money. I have accepted this new position.  So now, I need to approach my boss.

Our work environment is very small and I will see her every day after I give  notice.  I am very nervous and don't like to quit jobs, but I need this new job, no if ands or buts about it. There are only three employees here including myself and my boss, and the other employee is only part time.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi @KRyan I edited your question so other users could better understand it and the question you are asking.

Comment: "What is the best way...?" In person. "I will see her every day" and "there are only three employees" should not really change how you resign.

Comment: Depending on what exactly your question is, this might be relevant / a duplicate - [How do I resign without burning bridges when I'm a critical staff member?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/56611) Also, [How does one title a resignation email?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/34995) [Should letter of resignation be honest or formal?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/42321) [How can one resign from a new job gracefully?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7149)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tell my boss I quit?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9074/how-do-i-tell-my-boss-i-quit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, what is the best way to approach my boss with my 2
>   week resignation? Our work environment is very small and I will see
>   her everyday after I give her my notice.

Assuming you have no flexibility with your new employer, just give the notice and work out the notice period. If you do have flexibility, you might consider offering more notice period if that would help.

Ask for specific things you can do to make it easier on the other 2 employees.

Yes, it will be awkward. But that's just the way things are. These things happen.

Answer (score 1):

If she is professional, she will have to accept it. So typically you should just pass it to her, explain your reasons, and prepare for the technicalities (leaving date, handing over work  etc) before meeting her so that the meeting does not go weird over something unnecessary.

Comment: This should be a comment, rather than an answer... could you please elaborate?